# Chrome key events alt key locks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In chrome, it seems that pressing alt will lock keydown/keyup callbacks.
To reproduce, enter the following in a js console on any page:

```
var a = function(e){
console.log(e);
};
document.body.onkeydown = a;
document.body.onkeyup = a;
```

then click into the page and press keys, you should see key press and release events in the console.
But if you press alt repeatedly, you'll notice you only see events for every second key press. In fact, if you press alt once, then press other keys, the events are swallowed.
Am I going crazy? Wtf is this?
To clarify, everything seems to work fine in firefox.

EDIT: works fine on chromium on linux, doesn't work on two windows machines, one 7, one 8

Answer (score 3):

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the focus changes to the 3-bars menu icon in the top right corner, such that pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> would open said menu.

[image: Chrome Menu button location]

(Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> the second time will return focus to the web page.)

If this behavior is not desirable, you can try `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` in your `keydown` event. This may or may not work depending on browser restrictions on the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

On my Windows 7, Firefox will open the File, Edit, View, etc menus when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>. I am surprised if you are not seeing this behavior on yours.

[image: Firefox menus appear when you press Alt]